# Does Django version have Issue when you use different Dependecies version on Live Server?

Tags: python, django

I have developed my Django application using Django 4.2.5. Locally it is uploading and displaying images fine but on the production server it is uploading but not displaying the uploaded images. I have checked the URL of the images on my HTML Templates while on the server using DevTools but it seems to be pointing rightly. I don't know whether this has to do with some dependencies of some sort. So someone should help.
See my Model Code:

```
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill, Transpose
```

#File Extension Validator

```
@deconstructible
class FileExtensionValidator:
    """ImageKit Validation Decorator"""
    def __init__(self, extensions):
        self.extensions = extensions

def __call__(self, value):
    extension = value.name.split('.')[-1].lower()
    if extension not in self.extensions:
        valid_extensions = ', '.join(self.extensions)
        raise ValidationError(f"Invalid file extension. Only {valid_extensions} files are allowed.")

image_extensions = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)  # 'admin', 'cashier', 'customer'
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  
    image = ProcessedImageField(
                                    upload_to='profile_images',
                                    processors=[Transpose(), ResizeToFill(150, 200)],
                                    format='JPEG',
                                    options={'quality': 97},
                                    validators=[FileExtensionValidator(image_extensions)],
                                    default='avatar.jpg'
                                )
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}-Profile'
```

See the URL to displaying the images: `<img class="img-thumbnail" src=" {{ user.profile.image.url }} " alt="profile image">`
Also note that I have no problem with Media and static files but better understanding of my problem, the app is hosted on Whogohost.com so I don't know whether it's a problem with them. Here are the paths to my Media and Static files:

```
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/successdigits/public_html/smart/static'`

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('xxxx.urls')),
    path('', include('xxxxx.urls')), 
    path('404/', custom_page_not_found, name='custom_404'),
    path('403/', custom_page_forbidden, name='custom_403'),
    path('500/', custom_server_not_found, name='custom_500'),
]+ static ( settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```